# SSH copy 1000 files a time

Tags: ssh, copy

I have a folder with 30000 files. I want to copy 1000 files a time via SSH to another folder. I need to do that cause my script is timing out when I try to run it on all 30k.
Is that possible?

**EDIT**

Based on the comments.

I connect via putty. The script is executed from the user by clicking a button and it not the problem. I just want to move the files in batches and I don't want to do it via ftp.

Like the LIMIT command in SQL (LIMIT 0,1000 or LIMIT 1000,2000)

Comment: how about `rsync -r=ssh -avz ...`? Is this done in a web app?

Comment: You don't provide enough information to people to help you. What does the script look like? In what manner do you execute copy over/within ssh?

Comment: are you using pscp.exe from putty package?

Comment: No I don't. I connect from the putty.exe

Answer (score 1):

The best way to copy over `ssh` is by using `scp` (`pscp in putty`)

```
pscp.exe -r somedir me@server:/data/vol1
```

pscp.exe uses all settings from putty including authentication keys.

Comment: Is there a command that will copy the first 1000 like cp 0,1000 or cp 1000,2000 etc?

Comment: pscp.exe doesn't have such capability. On Linux bash normally I would make some nested scripting, but I have no idea how to do that in win batch script.